# Direct State Access (DSA) is Failing, but pre 4.3 OpenGL works

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad, direct-state-access

I currently have an OpenGL project in which I am using GLFW for the window and context creation, and GLAD for loading OpenGL functions. The GLAD version I am using is OpenGL 4.6, compatibility profile, with all extensions (including ARB_direct_state_access).

My current graphics card settings are

```
OpenGL Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 457.09
GLSL Version: 4.60 NVIDIA
Renderer: GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
```

When I run the following non-DSA code, it works fine.

```
// Create vertex array object and bind it
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Create an index buffer object and use the data in the indices vector
GLuint ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicies.size()*sizeof(GLint), indicies.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create a array buffer object and use the positional data which has x,y,z components
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), positions.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

However when I try to translate this code to a DSA format and run it, the program opens a window and then terminates without and useful debug information.

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

GLuint vbo;
glCreateBuffers(1, &vbo);
glNamedBufferStorage(vbo, positions.size()*sizeof(GLfloat), positions.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, vbo, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);

GLuint ibo;
glCreateBuffers(1, &ibo);
glNamedBufferStorage(ibo, sizeof(GLint)*indicies.size(), indicies.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(vao, ibo);
```

In both cases I bind the Vertex Array Object before drawing like so

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicies.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Why is my DSA like code not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) you must specify the ***stride*** argument. The special case in which the generic vertex attributes are understood as tightly packed when the *stride* is 0, as when using [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml), does not apply when using `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`.

<s>`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, vbo, 0, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, vbo, 0, 3*sizeof(float));
```

It won't cause an error if *stride* is 0, but that doesn't mean it makes sense.

Comment: Wow, I feel like I would have never caught such a detail. Thank you so much for the help!